# Good Selenium WebDriver Extension?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, browser-automation

I noticed that the webdriver doesnt have much support for .net. There are plenty of functions for java and ruby but C# is kinda lagging far... behind.

Does anybody know of any extensions classes or libraries that help C# testers. Currently converting tests from Watin to Selenium and I'm starting to realize selenium does not have a ton of support for things like the table class, select lists, ect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try. We use it, and love it.

[Selenium WebDriverSEd Nuget](https://nuget.org/packages/WebDriverSEd/1.0.0.0)

[Selenium WebDriverSEd GitHub](https://github.com/Assiance/Selenium2-WebDriverSEd)

Answer (score 1):

Shameless self-plug (because I'm on the dev team for this framework):

Try: http://webinator.codeplex.com/

Comment: What about Chrome and IE support? If webinator supports it, it's likely I might start to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the C# Client Driver from Selenium? http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-dotnet-2.17.0.zip

I'm using it and I can use XPath with it as well:

```
 _ieWebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.co.uk");
 IWebElement queryBox = _ieWebDriver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
 queryBox.FindElement(By.XPath(""));
```

For Table Class with Selenium, you may like to have a look at [FITNESSE](http://fitnesse.org/) to be used with Selenium.